# Fusing Multiple Laser Scans

Tags: ros, laser, rplidar, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a RPLIDAR A2 and an  Orbbec Astra. The former is the one I am using for my gmapping at the moment and most of the time it  works really well. I was wondering about fusing its (forward scans) with the same range from the Astra. Just to help ensure accuracy from both the sensors....

Is there any point in doing this? And how could I go about it?

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258766/fusing-multiple-laser-scans/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while, I did a fusion between rplidar and Asus xtion pro, and it works fun now. Due to roswiki is down now, could you please put more information about Orbbec Astra?

---

Originally posted by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) with karma: 188 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skydddive](https://answers.ros.org/users/36186/skydddive/) on 2018-07-01**:
hello,I'm a student from china.i want to learn more about your work about data fusion between rplidar and camera.I have a rplidar A2 and a kinect camera.